# npm через proxy сервер

Tags: proxy, npm

На рабочем компе не получается загрузить пакеты через `npm`. Проблема в том, что в компании все работает через proxy сервер.
Прокси прописал таким способом:

```
npm config set http-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Но по-прежнему не загружает пакеты, ругается на соединение. 
Кто юзает `npm` подобным способом, подскажите что делать.

Насколько я понимаю нужно прописывать еще логин и пароль. 
Я сделал это так:

```
npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@proxy.company.com:8080
```

Не помогло.

Comment: В моем случае ничего не сработало.
Прокси на моей фирме не требует авторизации, т.е. у меня нет логина и пароля.
При попытке установки любого пакета nmp выдает ошибку 503:
error 503 Service Unavailable: <имя пакета>@latest.
Все остальные программы (git, chrome, webstorm и все остальное ПО) работают через этот прокси, только nodejs + npm не хочет.
Пообщаюсь с сисадмином нашей корпоративной сети и если решится проблема, то сообщу в чем было дело.
При этом на двух домашних машинах все работает отлично. Везде Win10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нашел решение, в файле `C:\Users\<username>\.npmrc` нужно было прописать в данном виде:

```
proxy=http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080/
https-proxy=http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080/
```

Через команду `npm config set proxy <proxy>` тоже будет работать, т.к данная команда записывает конфигурацию в этот же файл.